# Index Route vs Custom Route causes application.hbs model issues

Tags: ember.js

I am working with Ember 2.9, and I'm facing a weird routing + model issue.

I have two routes that are identical (copied and pasted code inside the route) except for the pathing. I have one route which is '/', and another route which is 'my-route'.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        let dict = {
            myLog1Model: this.get('store').findAll('my-log1'),
            myLog2Model: this.get('store').findAll('my-log2'),
            myLog3Model: this.get('store').findAll('my-log3'),
            myLog4Model: this.get('store').findAll('my-log4')
        };
        return dict;
    }
});
```

When I access my ember application from localhost/ all model data is displayed properly, but when I access it from localhost/my-route none of the model data is being passed around in application.hbs

application.hbs

```
<section class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            {{control-panel model=model}}
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            {{log-panel model=model}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

log-panel.hbs

```
{{myLog1 model=model.myLog1Model}}
{{myLog2 model=model.myLog2Model}}
{{myLog3 model=model.myLog3Model}}
{{myLog4 model=model.myLog4Model}}
```

Ember tables takes it from here...
myLog1.hbs

```
{{models-table
    data=model
    columns=columns
    useNumericPagination=true}}
```

As I stated before this works perfectly fine with 'localhost/', but not with 'localhost/my-route'. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue, by loading any application model data in the Application Route. I had no idea that there was a difference between '/', and the application route.

Comment: This is explained in https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_the-application-route.